Google Search Console Site map can't be fetched Error
My website has multiple sitemaps. when I Submitted them in the Google Search console I got an error Couldn't fetch as shown in the image below.

Please answer me, what is the reason for this error. I am submitting the sitemaps one by one without any time break, Is this a reason of this error?

Give it some time. Say a day or two. It can sometimes mean it has not tried to fetch yet.

If you are submitting them manually, the not is unlikely that you are going too fast.  The most likely scenario is that the path you are typing is not correct.
